# Does object instantiation time depend on its size?

Tags: java, microbenchmark

We know that object size depends on its field type. But does object instantiation time depend on its fields type? See my test

```
public class Test {
    byte f1;
    byte f2;
    byte f3;
    byte f4;
    byte f5;
    byte f6;
    byte f7;
    byte f8;
    byte f9;
    byte f10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1000000;
        Test[] a = new Test[n];
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = new Test();
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);
    }
}
```

Maybe not first class, still gives me rather stable results for different field types:

```
byte - 125 ms
int  - 250 ms
long - 370 ms
```

Why is that? I ran it from Eclipse on my notebook (Celeron 925), it needs -Xmx1024M.

Comment: what is your question?  larger types give you slowe runtime. What is unexpected?

Comment: my question is why larger types are instantiated longer

Comment: because, even assuming constant memory allocation time (which is probably not the case) you still need to set all the memory to 0 and it takes longer to set more memory to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Larger** types will require **more time** as the OS has to **search** suitable amount of memory in the **HEAP** to fit that type. So the larger the type, it will require more time generally.

Most of the time **Object instantiation time directly proportional to fields types**

Comment: also if your memory is fragmented then the time required can be more than normal

Comment: this is implementation details, but it will definitely take longer to set a long to 0 then a byte.